# Alamofire dealing with special character parameters

Tags: swift, url, utf-8, alamofire

the ServiceKey I got for the api is mixed with complex characters, like D%2FFgugDIl1le9xiY7be1ge%2B0Q%3D%3D

and when I put the key in the params of alamofire and use the .get keyword, my key transforms and when the url is actually created, it becomes a totally different key.

is there any way to solve this problem?

This is the code I am using

```
Alamofire.request(BusURL, method: .get, parameters: ["cityCode": 25, "routeId":"DJB30300052ND", "ServiceKey": key])
        .responseString { response in
            print(" - API url: \(String(describing: response.request!))")   // original url request
            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                if let string = response.result.value {
                    print("XML: \(string)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                statusCode = error._code // statusCode private
                print("status code is: \(String(describing: statusCode))")
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

Comment: what are you passing in `key`

Comment: The ServiceKey inside params array gets rendered weird on the actual url

Comment: Assuming your `D%2FFgugDIl1le9xiY7be1ge%2B0Q%3D%3D` is pre-escaped, you need to pass unescaped value to the API. Try with `D/FgugDIl1le9xiY7be1ge+0Q==` .

Comment: Is there any way to make it unescapted programmatically?

Comment: Yes.Try `key.removingPercentEncoding!`

Comment: hmm actually that brought a different key value still but thank you still :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
let params = ["cityCode": "25", "routeId":"DJB30300052ND"]
        var urlParams = params.flatMap({ (key, value) -> String in
            return "\(key)=\(value)"
        }).joined(separator: "&")

        let key = "&ServiceKey=D%2FFgugDIl1le9xiY7be1ge%2B0Q%3D%3D"
        urlParams.append(key)

        let url = "https://google.com?\(urlParams)"
        print("url\(url)")
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).validate().responseString(completionHandler: {response in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                let s = response.result.value ?? "Empty Result"
                print("response \(s)")
            case .failure:
                print("Call Failed")
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        })
```

output: `https://google.com?cityCode=25&routeId=DJB30300052ND&ServiceKey=D%2FFgugDIl1le9xiY7be1ge%2B0Q%3D%3D`

Comment: I forgot that I can always hard code.. Thank you so much!